# Stop embedded Windows Media Player from looping?

Tags: html, audio, audio-streaming, wmp, embedded-control

I've got an embedded Windows Media player in an HTML page, and when the audio gets to the end, it just starts again from the beginning.

According to the documentation, there's an `autorewind` parameter/attribute and also a `loop`.

The problem is, I've set both of those to `false` (and/or zero) and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Might this be a bug? My client is WMP 10.00.00.4058. Maybe there's some kind of setting on the *server* which tells files to loop, is that a crazy idea?

Answer (score 2):

WTH! param name=PlayCount value=1

Answer (score 1):

The issue, i believe, lies within your different embedding methods between the different browsers.  Here's is some tested code where looping does not happen.

IE

```
<object id="contentPlayer" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" width="300" height="60"><!-- <param name='fileName' value=''> -->
<param name='animationatStart' value='false'>
<param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
<param name='autoStart' value='true'>
<param name='playState' VALUE='1'>
<param name='loop' value='false'>
</OBJECT>
```

Firefox

```
<object id="contentPlayer" name='contentPlayer' type="application/x-ms-wmp" data="" width="300" height="60"><!-- <param name='fileName' value=''> -->
<param name='animationatStart' value='false'>
<param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
<param name='autoStart' value='true'>
<param name='playState' VALUE='1'>
<param name='loop' value='false'>
</OBJECT>
```

The primary difference being that in IE I have a classid but in Firefox I have a "type" classification

Answer (score 0):

compare your html code with this:

stolen from
http://www.programmingforums.org/post147977.html

> ```
> <object width="320" height="290"
> classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
> id="mediaplayer1">
> <param name="Filename" value="kids.mpg">
> <param name="AutoStart" value="True">
> <param name="ShowControls" value="True">
> <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="False">
> <param name="ShowDisplay" value="False">
> <param name="AutoRewind" value="True">
> <embed
> type="application/x-mplayer2"
> pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/"
> width="320" height="290" src="/support/dreamweaver/ts/documents/kids.mpg"
> filename="kids.mpg" autostart="True"
> showcontrols="True" showstatusbar="False"
> showdisplay="False" autorewind="True">
> </embed>
> </object>
> ```